# Backup DB data after Junit

Tags: java

when the Junit test is executed it deletes the orginal data of database how can i perform backup so that the data`s are retrieved after Junit test

```
@Test
public void testExecute_N001() throws Exception {
    this.importFileName_tsc = "input/input_tsc_" + "1" + EXTENSION_XML;
    this.importFileName_postgre = "input/input_eccube_" + "1"
            + EXTENSION_XML;
    this.resultFileName = "output/output_" + "1" + EXTENSION_XML;
    super.setResultBatchFilePrefix("N-001_");
    super.copyToImportFile("input/N-001" + EXTENSION_TXT);
    checkNoBatchTarget();
}

public void testExecute_N002() throws Exception {
    this.importFileName_tsc = "input/input_tsc_" + "1" + EXTENSION_XML;
    this.importFileName_postgre = "input/input_eccube_" + "1"
            + EXTENSION_XML;
    this.resultFileName = "output/output_" + "1" + EXTENSION_XML;

    super.setResultBatchFilePrefix("N-002_");
    super.copyToImportFile("input/N-002" + EXTENSION_TXT);
    checkBatchExecute();
}

public void testExecute_E001() throws Exception {
    this.importFileName_tsc = "input/input_tsc_" + "2" + EXTENSION_XML;
    this.importFileName_postgre = "input/input_eccube_" + "2"
            + EXTENSION_XML;
    this.resultFileName = "output/output_" + "2" + EXTENSION_XML;

    super.setResultBatchFilePrefix("E-001_");
    super.copyToImportFile("input/E-001" + EXTENSION_TXT);
    checkError();
}

private void checkNoBatchTarget() throws Exception {
    IDatabaseConnection ecCubeConn = null; // DBコネクション
    IDatabaseConnection connection = null; // DB POSTGRESQL

    try {
        connection = getConnection();

        IDataSet dataSet = getDataSetFromFile(this.importFileName_tsc);

        // 個別データ削除処理
        DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL.execute(connection, dataSet);

        // xmlからテストデータを取得し、テーブルにセットする
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(connection, dataSet);
        ecCubeConn = getConnection();

        IDataSet dataSet_postgre = getDataSetFromFile(this.importFileName_postgre);
        DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL.execute(ecCubeConn, dataSet_postgre);
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(ecCubeConn, dataSet_postgre);

        int result = super.batchStart(args);

        // 戻り値チェック
        assertEquals("0", String.valueOf(result));

        // DBテーブルチェック
        // 期待されるデータを取得
        IDataSet expectedDataSet = getDataSetFromFile(this.resultFileName);

        QueryDataSet queryDataSet = new QueryDataSet(ecCubeConn);
        queryDataSet
                .addTable(
                        DESTINATION_TABLE_1,
                        "SELECT  store_cd, store_name, area_id, product_code, goods_code, maker_id, maker_product_code, size, color, stock, season FROM "
                                + DESTINATION_TABLE_1);
        IDataSet databaseDataSet = queryDataSet;

        ITable expectedTableOrd = sortTable(expectedDataSet);
        ITable actualTableOrd = sortTable(databaseDataSet);

        // REMOVE UNNECESSARY COLUMNS FOR TESTING
        expectedTableOrd = DefaultColumnFilter.includedColumnsTable(
                expectedTableOrd, new String[] { "store_cd", "store_name",
                        " area_id", "product_code", "goods_code",
                        "maker_id", "maker_product_code", "size", "color",
                        "stock", "season" });

        // 更新されていることを確認
        Assertion.assertEquals(expectedTableOrd, actualTableOrd);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (super.isBatchFile()) {
            super.moveToBackup();
        }

        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
}

private void checkError() throws Exception {
    IDatabaseConnection connection = null; // DBコネクション
    IDatabaseConnection ecCubeConn = null; // DB POSTGRESQL

    try {
        connection = getConnection();
        IDataSet dataSet = getDataSetFromFile(this.importFileName_tsc);
        DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL.execute(connection, dataSet);
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(connection, dataSet);
        ecCubeConn = getConnection();
        IDataSet dataSet_postgre = getDataSetFromFile(this.importFileName_postgre);
        DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL.execute(ecCubeConn, dataSet_postgre);
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(ecCubeConn, dataSet_postgre);

        int result = super.batchStart(args);

        assertEquals("-1", String.valueOf(result));

        IDataSet expectedDataSet = getDataSetFromFile(this.resultFileName);

        QueryDataSet queryDataSet = new QueryDataSet(ecCubeConn);
        queryDataSet
                .addTable(
                        DESTINATION_TABLE_1,
                        "SELECT  store_cd,, store_name, area_id, product_code, goods_code, maker_id, maker_product_code, size, color, stock, season  FROM "
                                + DESTINATION_TABLE_1);
        IDataSet databaseDataSet = queryDataSet;

        ITable expectedTableOrd = sortTable(expectedDataSet);
        ITable actualTableOrd = sortTable(databaseDataSet);

        expectedTableOrd = DefaultColumnFilter.includedColumnsTable(
                expectedTableOrd, new String[] { "store_cd", "store_name",
                        " area_id", "product_code", "goods_code",
                        "maker_id", "maker_product_code", "size", "color",
                        "stock", "season" });

        Assertion.assertEquals(expectedTableOrd, actualTableOrd);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (super.isBatchFile()) {
            super.moveToBackup();
        }

        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
}

private void checkBatchExecute() throws Exception {
    IDatabaseConnection connection = null; // DBコネクション
    IDatabaseConnection ecCubeConn = null; // DB POSTGRESQL

    try {
        connection = getConnection();
        IDataSet dataSet = getDataSetFromFile(this.importFileName_tsc);
        DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL.execute(connection, dataSet);
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(connection, dataSet);
        ecCubeConn = getConnection();
        IDataSet dataSet_postgre = getDataSetFromFile(this.importFileName_postgre);
        DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL.execute(ecCubeConn, dataSet_postgre);
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(ecCubeConn, dataSet_postgre);
        int result = super.batchStart(args);
        assertEquals("0", String.valueOf(result));

        IDataSet expectedDataSet = getDataSetFromFile(this.resultFileName);
        QueryDataSet queryDataSet = new QueryDataSet(ecCubeConn);
        queryDataSet
                .addTable(
                        DESTINATION_TABLE_1,
                        "SELECT store_cd,, store_name, area_id, product_code, goods_code, maker_id, maker_product_code, size, color, stock, season  FROM "
                                + DESTINATION_TABLE_1);
        IDataSet databaseDataSet = queryDataSet;

        ITable expectedTableOrd = sortTable(expectedDataSet);
        ITable actualTableOrd = sortTable(databaseDataSet);

        expectedTableOrd = DefaultColumnFilter.includedColumnsTable(
                expectedTableOrd, new String[] { "store_cd", "store_name",
                        " area_id", "product_code", "goods_code",
                        "maker_id", "maker_product_code", "size", "color",
                        "stock", "season" });
        Assertion.assertEquals(expectedTableOrd, actualTableOrd);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (super.isBatchFile()) {
            super.moveToBackup();
        }

        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
}

private ITable sortTable(IDataSet dataSet) throws DataSetException {
    return new SortedTable(dataSet.getTable(DESTINATION_TABLE_1),
            new String[] { "store_cd" });
}
```

is there any other easy way to check insert update and delete in database.....
is this method ok...
how this code can be impoved......
is there any other way to implement this so that it will not effect the database datas..

Answer (score 0):

1. If possible, have a separate environment where you can run tests. I hope you are not running your tests in a production environment.
2. Never use the actual data to run your tests. Always setup data and run your tests on them. If you use actual data, there is no guarantee that it will always be there so there are chances of your tests failing in future.
3. Perform database inserts/updates within a transaction and roll back in the end after performing your tests.